# how to pull information out of html with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hta

I have this set of code that will be links to sections of the hta page:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>Windows 10</strong> comes with a new design and features.</li><br><br>
    <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Edge">Microsoft-Edge</a></strong> has been introduced as Microsoft's next generation web browser.</li><br><br>
    <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Skype">Microsoft Skype for Business</a></strong> is the Lync that you know . </li><br><br>
    <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="FindPrinter">Printer list</a></strong> ........... </li><br><br>
    <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Email">Email Signature</a></strong> ........... </li>
</ul>
```

I want Microsoft edge, Microsoft skype for business, printer list, and Email signature to be the links and depending on which link is clicked the JavaScript will use `slider.gotoslide(x)` here:

```
    $('div.Welcome a').click(function(){
        var itemClicked = 'div.Welcome a';
        if (itemClicked.index() === 0){  //Microsoft Edge
            slider.goToSlide(6); //slide 6
        }
        else if (itemClicked.index() === 1) { //Microsoft Skype for Business
            slider.goToSlide(10); //slide 10
        }
        else if (itemClicked.index() === 2) { //Find and Add Printers
            slider.goToSlide(15); //slide 15
        }
        else if (itemClicked.index() === 3) { // Email Signature
            slider.goToSlide(11); //slide 11
        }
        return false;
    });
```

As you can see I need the `div.welcome a` to give me which link was clicked on and then the if statements to tell me which slide to go to. However index is saying that

> Object doesn't support property or method "index"

Comment: `</li><br><br>`? That's invalid html... `<ul>` and `<ol>` cannot contain anything other than `<li>`

Comment: Marc B, then what would be the proper way to do it? This seems to work. I know that even if it works it might not be correct but if you are going to say something is invalid it would be nice for you to explain how to do it properly so I can learn

Comment: I already told you: `<ul>` and `<ol>` cannot contain anything other than `<li>`. if you want line breaks in the list, put them INSIDE the `<li>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$(this)` .

With the above expression you are converting/wrapping the element invoked (`this`) (*clicked anchor tag in this case*) with jQuery. So the result of this expression will be a jQuery object.

```
$(function(){

   $('div.Welcome a').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();  //prevent default link click behaviour

       var itemClicked = $(this);

       var id = itemClicked.attr("id");  //get the Id of the clicked a tag

       alert(id);
      //use id for your further code now

   });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zurako/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working jsBin sample.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like all you need to change is

```js
var item = 'div.welcom a' to $('div.Welcome a');
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because that wouldn't give you the element that was clicked, it would give you all of the elements matching that selector.

Comment: Yea, just realized that it was a class selector... oops. $(this) FTW